# Can't write to Kafka topics

Tags: google-compute-engine, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, google-cloud-platform, hortonworks-data-platform

I have [Hortonworks Data Platform on Google Cloud](http://hortonworks.com/blog/hdp-google-cloud-platform/). Ambari says that both Kafka and Zookeeper are running, but I can't write any data to kafka topics. For example,

```
[mpcs53013@hadoop-m ~]$ /usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list 10.240.0.5:6667 --topic mpstest2
a
[2015-11-18 04:15:05,800] WARN Error while fetching metadata [{TopicMetadata for topic mpstest2 -> 
No partition metadata for topic mpstest2 due to kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableException}] for topic [mpstest2]: class kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableException  (kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo)
```

This happens with every topic I create.

The lack of a leader suggests that zookeeper isn't cooperating, but not sure how to diagnose. If I ask Kafka to describe the topic, it also says there is no leader.

[edit] After much experimentation, it seems that /kafka/brokers/0 is missing the "endpoints" section in zookeeper.

```
get /brokers/ids/0
{"jmx_port":-1,"timestamp":"1447878898217","host":"hadoop-m.c.mpcs53013-2015.internal","version":1,"port":6667}
...
```

If I manually edit the zookeeper data

```
set /brokers/ids/0 {"jmx_port":-1,"timestamp":"1447878898217","endpoints":["PLAINTEXT://hadoop-m.c.mpcs53013-2015.internal:6667"],"host":"hadoop-m.c.mpcs53013-2015.internal","version":1,"port":6667}
```

Then everything works!

So I guess that leaves me with the question of "Why aren't the endpoints getting filled in in zookeeper?"

Any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe a version mismatch between the kafka version that your brokers are running versus the version of the clients used to write to (or describe) the topics?

Comment: What versions are/were you using? 
BTW. Check general communication between Kafka broker and Zookeeper.